# How would this 'for' be done in Java in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

1. This would be the 'for' in Java of any class

Abstract classes

```
abstract class ResourceRequester
{
    Response run(Request paramRequest);
}

abstract class QueueStorage<Element>
{
    bool isEmpty();
    void add(Element paramElement);
    Map<int, Element> get();
    void dequeue(int paramInteger);
    int size();
}
```

and other class

```java
ResourceRequester requester; 
QueueStorage<Request> queue;

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Request> entry : (Iterable<Map.Entry<Integer, Request>>)this.queue.get().entrySet()) {
    try {
        this.requester.run(entry.getValue());
        this.queue.dequeue(entry.getKey());
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        this.logger.info("Failed to flush", (Throwable)e);
    } 
}
```

What would it be like on Dart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want but here is a simple example of how you can make a for-each loop of a Map in Dart:

```
void main() {
  Map<int, String> queue = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'};

  for (final entry in queue.entries) {
    final key = entry.key;
    final value = entry.value;

    print('Key: $key Value: $value');
  }
}
```

If the code are more simple (like my example) the same can be done with the `forEach` method on the map:

```
void main() {
  Map<int, String> queue = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'};
  queue.forEach((key, value) => print('Key: $key Value: $value'));
}
```

**Update after more complete example:**
You can do it like. I have added empty classes for `Response`, `Request` and `HttpException` since I can't see where they comes from:

```
class Response {}
class Request {}
class HttpException {}

abstract class ResourceRequester {
  Response run(Request paramRequest);
}

abstract class QueueStorage<T> {
  bool isEmpty();
  void add(T paramElement);
  Map<int, T> get();
  void dequeue(int paramInteger);
  int size();
}

class OtherClass {
  ResourceRequester requester;
  QueueStorage<Request> queue;

  void someMethod() {
    for (final entry in this.queue.get().entries) {
      try {
        this.requester.run(entry.value);
        this.queue.dequeue(entry.key);
      } on HttpException catch (ex) {
        print('Failed to flush: ${ex.toString()}');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I already knew how to do that, but I mean translating that Java code to Dart, calling other classes that are the ones that fetch data

Comment: Well, if you need a direct translation you need to give a lot more context. E.g. what class is `this`? What type is `requester`, `queue` and `logger`? Since I don't know any of that, I can only assume you want help with the `for` part.

Comment: Are called to other abstract classes

`abstract class ResourceRequester
{
    Response run(Request paramRequest);
}`

`abstract class QueueStorage<Element>
{
    bool isEmpty();

    void add(Element paramElement);

    Map<int, Element> get();

    void dequeue(int paramInteger);

    int size();
}`



`ResourceRequester requester; QueueStorage<Request> queue;`

Comment: Please update your question with this details since it is quite unreadable as comments.

Comment: I have updated my answer with my take on how to write the same code in Dart. It is not that different from the Java code besides the for-each syntax.